# Find max of a column and its category

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table like this:

```
Date          Category     quantity
2022-04-15    A            500
2022-04-15    B            700
2022-04-15    F            900
2022-04-16    M            400
```

I want to find the highest quantity per day but I want to see the category as well like this:

```
Date          Category     quantity
2022-04-15    F            900
2022-04-16    M            400
```

The easiest way to write the query is:

```
SELECT Date, max(quantity)
FROM table
GROUP BY Date
```

But it does not show the category. Is there any way to do it without using join?

Comment: Just add Category in the SELECT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `ROW_NUMBER` here:

```sql
SELECT Date, Category, quantity
FROM yourTable
WHERE 1 = 1
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Date ORDER BY quantity DESC) = 1;
```